# Zsh parameter expansion

Tags: zsh, variable-substitution

I tried to display the content of the variable fpath in column form using parameter expansion, and I couldn't do it.

After some trying and web browsing I just found another solution; which does exactly what I want. It is:

```
print -C1 $fpath
```

But I still wonder how to do it the other way. The closest I got was:

```
echo ${fpath//' '/'\n'}
```

But I fail to identify the white space character, so the '\n' substitution never takes place. I tried to no avail:

```
echo ${fpath// /'\n'}
echo ${fpath//'\t'/'\n'}
```

I wonder, out of curiosity, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fpath` is an array. You should not try to demote it to a string and then replace characters in it with newlines.

With `ksh`-like array expansion syntax:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${fpath[@]}"
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/5.7.1/functions
```

With `zsh`, you can also use `"$fpath[@]"` or `"${(@)fpath}"`.

You can also do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' $fpath
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/5.7.1/functions
```

But note that it skips empty elements of the array (likely not a problem for `$fpath`).

`zsh`'s `print` builtin can also print elements one per line with the `-l` option. Like in `ksh` where the `print` builtin comes from, you do need the `-r` option though to print arbitrary data raw, so:

```
print -rl -- $fpath
```

would be equivalent to the standard `printf '%s\n'`.

They differ from `-C1` when `$fpath` is an empty list in which case `print -rC1 -- $fpath` outputs nothing while `print -rl` and `printf '%s\n'` output one empty line, so

```
print -rC1 -- "$array[@]"
```

is probably the closest to what you want to print elements of the array one per line which in `bash`/`ksh` you could write:

```
[ "${#array[@]}" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right, that did the trick.

Comment: This is zsh, and `$fpath` shouldn't contain empty entries, so you can just write `$fpath`, no need for the ksh backward compatibility pinkie-destroying syntax.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the heads-up.